# Does the Emscripten's VR API utilize the WEBGL_MULTIVIEW_EXTENSION?

Tags: emscripten, webvr, webassembly

I'm working on auditing the code, but hoping for a definitive answer: Does Emscripten's VR API utilize the WebGL-Multiview-Extension to avoid making redundant calculations to render multiple viewports in a single draw call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, emscripten VR API currently does not make use of WEBGL_MULTIVIEW_EXTENSION.

Since there will eventually be a rewrite to wrap WebXR Device API (Emscripten VR API uses WebVR 1.1), I am unsure whether it would make sense to work on this, but if you have some spare time, give it a go!

Cheers, Jonathan (Squareys)

Comment: I'd would love to implement this, yet am not sure if I'm up to getting under the hood of Emscripten. The only thing I've ever written that's even *close* to a compiler is a 3d-slicer.

Hopefully, this will be implemented, as it represents a huge boost to VR performance.